# Do I need to encode individual diacritics in Spanish if I'm using a UTF-8 meta tag?

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding

I’m working on a couple of Spanish HTML emails and there are about five paragraphs of live text (disclaimers, etc.) Do I need to encode all of the diacritics (accented characters) in those html paragraphs if I’m using a UTF-8 meta tag in my head section?

The characters (and their accents) show up just fine when I copy them from InDesign to Atom (and they render fine as well on my browser), but I don’t want to leave the rendering to chance since this is an HTML email, and email clients are known to be dodgy.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Is this enough to properly render the accented characters in my html emails or do I need to encode each one separately?

Comment: What do you mean by encode? Something like `&eacute;`, or actual character encoding (UTF-8 versus Latin-1/CP-1252...)?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes, I mean do I need to encode each accented letter (for instance, convert an individual accented "é" to the `&eacute;`) if I'm using the '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">' tag?

To be clear, when I copy and paste the paragraph text from InDesign to Atom, an accented 'é' (for instance) looks right and renders right in the browser, but I'm unsure if that is enough to guarantee it looking correct when it goes out as part of an HTML email or if I should take the extra step of encoding each one to guarantee they look right.

Comment: You should verify that Atom actually saves the file with UTF-8. Then I guess your good, no need to replace "é" with `&eacute;`.